# libpcap, save selcetive region of my packet to pcap file

Tags: c, pcap, libpcap, wifi

I captured beacon file in (Linux ubuntu, c, monitor mode) by using libpcap filter like below

```
char *filter = "wlan type mgt subtype beacon";
pcap_compile(pcd,&bpg,filter,-1,PCAP_NETMASK_UNKNOWN);
pcap_setfilter(pcd, &bpg);
```

I captured beacon frame but it include radiotap header. (pcak datalink returns IEEE_802_11_RADIO)

but I want to save only beacon frame(remove radiotap header) to pcap file.
but i cannot find such kind of options in function pcap_dump()

Is there any method to save selective parts(remove radiotap part) of packet??
or Is there any filtering option that helps me to get only beacon frame without radiotap??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any method to save selective parts(remove radiotap part) of packet??

Yes.

First, if you're writing to a pcap file (which I'm assuming you're doing, as you mentioned `pcap_dump()`), do *NOT* use the `pcap_t` you got when you opened the Wi-Fi adapter as the argument to `pcap_dump_open()`, as you will *NOT* be writing packets with radiotap headers to the pcap file, and passing the `pcap_t` you got when you opened the Wi-Fi adapter as the argument to `pcap_dump_open()` will mean that the file's link-layer header type will be `DLT_IEEE802_11_RADIO`, which means the file will be interpreted by other programs as having packets with radiotap headers.

Instead, use `pcap_open_dead()` to create a fake `pcap_t`, and use `DLT_IEEE802_11` as its link-layer header type, and use *that* in the `pcap_dump_open()` call.

Then, for each packet:

First, make sure that the "on-the-network length" (the `len` field of the `struct pcap_pkthdr` for the packet, as provided to your program by libpcap) is >= 4 bytes and, if not, reject the packet.  That would mean the packet wasn't long enough to have a full radiotap header, which probably means there's a bug in the driver.

Then, make sure that the "captured data length" (the `caplen` field of the `struct pcap_pkthdr` for the packet, as provided to your program by libpcap) is >= 4 bytes and, if not, reject the packet.  That would mean that there isn't enough captured data for a full radiotap header, which probably means your program specified a snapshot length that was too short.

Then fetch the `it_len` field from the [radiotap header](http://www.radiotap.org) at the beginning of the packet.  Note that it's little-endian, not big-endian, so you don't need to byte-swap it on little-endian processors (such as 32-bit and 64-bit x86 processors), and you *do* need to byte-swap it on big-endian processors (such as PowerPC when running Linux).

Then check to make sure the `len` and `caplen` fields of the `struct pcap_pkthdr` for the packet are both >= the `it_len` value.

Then copy the `struct pcap_pkthdr` for the packet to a separate `struct pcap_pkthdr` variable, subtract `it_len` from that separate `struct pcap_pkthdr` variable's `len` and `caplen` variables, get a pointer that points `it_len` bytes past the beginning of the packet, and pass that pointer, and a pointer to the `struct pcap_pkthdr` variable from which you've subtracted `it_len` from the `len` and `caplen` values, to `pcap_dump()`.

Comment: REALLY THANKS A LOT, that is what i EXACTLY want to do.